# Pyqtgraph ImageView problem: ImageItem gets displayed outside of visible space of ViewBox

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am working on a GUI that at one point should display a long horizontal ROI of a camera feed. For that I am writing a widget consisting of an ImageView that is using a ViewBox and an ImageItem and then add that widget to a constrained space on a layout of the GUI. My problem is that the image from the camera is not visible upon opening the window but 'hidden' outside of the field of view of the widget (a little bit down). Upon resizing the window, it appears centered.
[This is how it looks after resizing before that it is where the arrow indicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J18cA.png)

This is a minimal version of the display widget in question:

```
class CameraViewerWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.viewport = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.view = self.viewport.addViewBox(lockAspect=False, enableMenu=True)
        self.img = pg.ImageItem()
        self.view.addItem(self.img)
        self.imv = pg.ImageView(view=self.view, imageItem=self.img)
        layout = self.layout()
        layout.addWidget(self.imv)
    def update_image(self, image, auto_range=True, auto_histogram_range=False):
        self.imv.setImage(image, autoRange=auto_range, autoHistogramRange=auto_histogram_range)
```

It is then added to the GUI via `addWidget()` and `update_image()` is called repeatedly using a QTimer.

Obviously the `auto_range` argument does not help here. I also tried to use the `setLimits()` and `setRange()` methods of the ViewBox but that also did not change the situation. I am suspecting that as I add this Widget to a contrained size on the layout of the main GUI (`maximumSize = 100`) the ImageView *does not know* how much space it has but I am not sure how to test that and a bit confused by the different coordinate systems used here. Did anyone encounter similar issues or is able to see my error here?

Comment: What is `get_layout`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Sorry some inaccuracies, it should be layout()